# Java Interfaces and Inheritance and Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

To conceptually understand inheritance, interfaces & polymorphism, I created a couple of classes to test things. The result I am getting is not the one I expected. The code is as follows:

```
public class Animal implements Comparable{
//Animal constructor & methods
public int compareTo(Object arg0){System.out.println("Animal.compareTo");}
}

public class Bear extends Animal{
//Bear constructor & methods
}

public class PolarBear extends Bear implements Comparable{
//PolarBear constructor & methods
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {System.out.println("PolarBear.compareTo");
```

I don't get any error saying that I can't implement Comparable again. But in my testing, I can't get back to Animal's compareTo method once I create a PolarBear, even though PolarBear should inherit the Animal's compareTo. I tested the following:

```
Animal bobo = new PolarBear();
bobo.compareTo(null);
((PolarBear) bobo).compareTo(null);
((Animal)bobo).compareTo(null);
((Comparable) bobo).compareTo(null);
```

And each of them printed:

```
 PolarBear.compareTo
```

Is there any way to access the `Animal`'s `compareTo`? Logically, wouldn't I want the ability to be able to compare the animal qualities of a `PolarBear`, as well as the `PolarBear` qualities?

Comment: You can always call `super.compareTo()` from the subclass.

Comment: The methods are dynamic bound to the instance. `bobo` is a `PolarBear` therefore always the `compareTo(...)` method of `PolarBear` is called. Why would you want something else to be called?

Comment: That should be `implements Comparable<Animal>` by the way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you are casting your `bobo` object to `PolarBear`, `Animal`, or `Comparable`, the run-time type of the object will always be `PolarBear` since you instantiated it as

```
Animal bobo = new PolarBear();
```

Therefore whenever you call `.compareTo(wtv)` it'll call the `PolarBear` implementation.

This is what Polymorphism is. Read up on [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) as that's how polymorphishm is implemented in java.

If you want to call the `compareTo(wtv)` method of your parent classes, then you have to do `super.compareTo(wtv)` inside any other subclass' methods.

Comment: The method needs to have super.compareTo?
What if I want to have 2 compareTo methods, one in Animal, one in PolarBear that compare different things?
Wouldn't putting super.compareTo in PolarBear.compareTo's method body lose that purpose?

Comment: It depends. Since you are overriding the method in `PolarBear`, you are, by calling `super.compareTo`, extending the functionality from the parent class. You don't have to do it. You won't be able to access the `Animal`'s compareTo directly from a `PolarBear` instance.

Comment: @user1901074 - most places that deal with comparisons in the java libraries allow you to provide a Comparator class that can compare the objects instead on relying on the objects being comparable. this is normally how you'd handle scenarios where you have several comparison implementations.

Answer (score 2):

compareTo and inheritence is generally a [tricky business](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10). in theory, having subclasses to a Comparable concrete superclass breaks the comparable contract. for example - suppose i have a superclass A that compares to other A's by checking fields a1 and a1. now lets add a subclass B that has an extra field b1. `anA.compareTo(aB)` would compare by a1 and a2 while `((A)aB).compareTo(anA)` would not do the same
as to your question - you can call the Animal version of compareTo only from the subclass itself, by doing something like

```
super.compareTo(<something>)
```

but not from "outside", as you've overridden the method. it is your responsibility to maintain the same "contract" to the outside world as the method you've just overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You can always call **super.compareTo(arg0)** from within your PolarBear to invoke the logic placed in Animal.compareTo.

Comment: You can only use super inside an object. You are doing that in a main function (which is an static function and does not belong to any object). You have to put the super call **inside** your PolarBear's compareTo method

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. the underlying object is of PolarBear class and you are changing the interface (Class that is used to hold the reference of the object) of the object every time.

JVM check at compile time whether a method in the interface (Class which is used to hold the reference of the object) exist or not but binding takes place at run time because Child (PolearBear) has that method so it will always run that.

> use super.compareTo() in order to call the parent method.